# how to create a directory that virtually has the contents of 2 other directories

Tags: windows-7, symlink

Is there a way in Windows 7 to create a directory that has as its virtual contents all the files and folders from 2 other actual directories?

I'm hoping I can define a single dir that reflects the contents of 2 other dirs via symblinks or something without having to copy files.

*edit: I need to be able to specify the combining dir as a filepath. Looks like using a library doesn't let me do this.

c:\actualdir1\ a,b

c:\actualdir2\ c,d

c:\virtualdir\ a,b,c,d

thanks

Comment: I ended up creating a batch script to create the dir of all the syminks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible without writing your own Shell Extension. However, depending on what you are looking for, perhaps using Windows 7 Libraries would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like libraries would be perfect for this. You can create a library and add folders to it from code, then use the library almost anywhere you would use a folder. You don't mention what language you want to use - for managed code the Windows API Code Pack has some wrappers for the shell stuff, and from C++ you can use shell APIs.

(If you're asking as a user then the answer is still libraries, but the question is offtopic and belongs on SuperUser.)

Comment: Would I be able to access the library with a filepath? I need to supply the filepath for a webproxy client app redirect config value.

Comment: @claya tell me the language and I can answer you

Comment: Hmm not programatically. It's an web proxy application called "Charles" similar to fiddler. To set up the 'Map local' directory I need to supply a path; it provides a UI for selecting the directory to map a url path to. I want that directory to be this combined directory that I illustrated above. Libraries are not selectable in the UI since they aren't directories

Comment: yeah, a path to a library is not the same at all. If the app wasn't written to work with libraries, it won't work. Shame. It's probably overkill but you could set up a shadow folder. Write a little app that monitors the library with a ShellObjectWatcher and copies new/changed files (or deletes files) to the shadow folder. Then give the shadow folder to the proxy app.